Как быстро скруглять углы выделения кнопки WPF
В WPF нельзя задать CornerRadius для кнопки, поэтому для этого я убираю Background и BorderTickness у кнопки, и делаю её с помощью Border. Всё окей, но при выделении радиус скругления кнопки остаётся такой-же, и если надо поменять цвет выделения, то приходиться менять шаблон кнопки. Но если в проекте много кнопок разного радиуса скругления, или хочу сделать разные цвета выделения, неудобно создавать каждый раз стиль для этого, или прописывать Template для каждой кнопки. Можно ли как-то это упростить, по типу того чтобы просто указывать CornerRadius для кнопки.
Можно ли как-то в шаблоне это забиндить. Я пробовал сделать это с помощью Tag для кнопки, чтобы CornerRadius был равен этому Tag, но забиндить значение Tag для CornerRadius не получается. Приходилось делать Trigger для каждого значения Tag, что если он равен 1 то CornerRaduis тоже один и так далее.
В общем вопрос можно ли как-то упростить указание CornerRadius для кнопки, или забиндить Tag для этого.

Хотите свой функционал любому контролу - создайте свой контрол, который будет основан на стандартном и иметь свое поведение, свой стиль, свои триггеры, и так далее. Использование Tag, как по мне, это сразу повод задуматься о правильности своих действий.

@EvgeniyZ Как сделать свой контрол?

ПКМ - Добавить - Пользовательский элемент управления (User Control), а уже дальше, ваши пожелания, ваш код, ваша реализация....

@EvgeniyZ А другим способом это нельзя реализовать? Задача просто задавать CornerRadius для кнопки.

Можно конечно, вариантов уйма, от банального стиля под каждую кнопку, до создания своего Attached Property. Но вы ведь ленитесь, раз ищите альтернативы, значит последнее не для вас, пилите стили тогда, что-то вроде <Button><Button.Resources><Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}"><Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="..."/></закрывашки>. Но советую не лениться, имеете повторения с изменениями - объединяйте в контрол и используйте его.

@EvgeniyZ Не очень ленюсь, просто ничего не знаю, только изучаю. Большое спасибо, последний вариант подходит, и буду пробовать делать свои контролы
